# meaning of pool number in default name of thread in ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I am using ScheduledExecutorService to maintain a thread pool of core size 10

> ScheduledExecutorService visiblityThreadPool =
>   Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);

Now in the log I see thredName as **pool-39-thread-3** .

I am ok with thread number 3 assuming that thread number can vary from 1 to 10 but how come the pool number in the name in 39 ?

What does 39 indicates here ? Please put some light on it.

Answer (score 0):

That string is the name prefix for `Thread` objects initialized from a `java.util.concurrent.Executors$DefaultThreadFactory`.

The [source code of this class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java#Executors.DefaultThreadFactory) looks like

```
/**
 * The default thread factory
 */
static class DefaultThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    private static final AtomicInteger poolNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
    private final ThreadGroup group;
    private final AtomicInteger threadNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
    private final String namePrefix;

    DefaultThreadFactory() {
        SecurityManager s = System.getSecurityManager();
        group = (s != null) ? s.getThreadGroup() :
                              Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
        namePrefix = "pool-" +
                      poolNumber.getAndIncrement() +
                     "-thread-";
    }

    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(group, r,
                              namePrefix + threadNumber.getAndIncrement(),
                              0);
        if (t.isDaemon())
            t.setDaemon(false);
        if (t.getPriority() != Thread.NORM_PRIORITY)
            t.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        return t;
    }
}
```

The number following the `pool-` is therefore generated from an `AtomicInteger` stored in a `static` field. Each `DefaultThreadFactory` instance gets an "id" of sorts, representing how many others instances where initialized before it (+1).

Since most `ExecutorService` factory methods in `Executors` make use of this `DefaultThreadFactory`, you can also assume that this number represents how many thread pools were created through the `ExecutorService`.

Comment: It's not how many thread pools were created; it's how many `DefaultThreadFactory` instances have been created.  I don't know why the JRE needs to create 39 thread factories, but it could do that without necessarily ever creating a single thread or a single thread pool.

Comment: Thanks for you replies. In my application I have invoked Executors.newScheduledThreadPool only once at the startup of the application . So ideally it should show pool_1 but i think In am using some 3rd party dependencies for example datastax driver, eureka client, embedded tomcat etc which might be creating lot of  DefaultThreadFactory  instances. Do you also feel the same ?

Comment: @Laxmikant Yeah, that's likely what is happening.